# app.request.method paremeter in template always gives GET after form submit

Tags: php, twig, symfony4

`{{ app.request.method }}` always results in GET after form submit

ProfielController.php

```
 /**
 * @Route("/edit_profile_meta", methods={"GET", "POST"}, name="user_edit_meta")
 */
public function edit_profile_meta(Request $request): Response
{

    $profile = $this->getProfile();
    $form = $this->createForm(ProfielType::class, $profile);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($profile);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'user.updated_successfully');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_edit_meta');
    }

    return $this->render('user/edit_meta.html.twig', [
        'profile' => $profile,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

_flash_messages.html.twig

```
{% if app.request.method == 'POST' %}
    <div class="messages">
        {% for type, messages in app.flashes %}
            {% for message in messages %}

                <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-{{ type }} fade in" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>

                    {{ message|trans }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

My form is rendered as a with method=post. Still my template tells me request = GET ?

Comment: You are redirecting after successful submission, and those are always done via `GET`. Submit an invalid form and you should see the `POST` request.

Comment: Right, but I want to show a succesfull submit message. So I should just remove the app.request.method check and all is okay?

Comment: You might want to check if *there are any* messages first, so you don't output an empty `div` but yes. And those would show on unsuccesful submission too (if you set any)